# Invoke-WebRequest error when running ps1 script

Tags: powershell, command-line

I am trying to write a ps 3.0 script that will post a list of 200 words to a web server. After I have prepared the list, I use:

> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method POST -Body $PostParams -OutFile C:...\upload_log.tmp.txt

When I run this script from the ISE editor it works fine. However, when I run it from outside the editor (cmd, ps shell, task scheduler) I get this error message:

> Invoke-WebRequest : You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have to use Invoke-WebRequest if it doesn't work in your particular case. And even if you want to use it, falling back to the underlying .NET class (HttpWebRequest) may help you find out what is wrong with your code. [Example](http://serverfault.com/questions/592605/strange-behavior-from-invoke-webrequest-in-scheduled-task).

Comment: I read the example and I am not sure how it applies here. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Without knowing the contents of `$PostParams` it's impossible to say

Comment: I am not sure the content of $postparams is the problem. When I run it from the ISE it works fine. It only has issues if I run it otherwise - like from powershell.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?